bitcoind.service file to automatically start on boot
hi all i'm noob so sorry in advance
i installed bitcoind.service and everything is fine untill i reboot the system.
here is screenshot

when i reboot the system it doesn't work and show me this

i installed bitcoin core on linux mint.
if i do journalctl -e show me this

can anyone help me please considering i'm a noob so i need commands in details
thanks

Try taking a look at the debug.log file in the .bitcoin directory, it should hopefully tell you more about the failure reason.
